# Limits for matrix size

Tags: java, eclipse, numbers, ejml

I started using EJML for matrix calculations . I want to know the limits of data a matrix can hold. To do this I used following lines and I faced a very strange problem.

```
DMatrixSparseCSC TesT = new DMatrixSparseCSC(175285 , 80201 );
    for (int i1 = 0 ; i1 < 17584 ; i1++) {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 5000 ; j++)
        TesT.set(i1, (int) Math.round(Math.random() * j), 1);
    }
```

When I try to debug this code after i1 reaches 218 and j reaches 2088 the debugger stops to do anything and got stuck on inner loop and all control buttons went to disabled state i.e "stepin" , "stepover" etc . Does anyone have an idea what could be the reason behind this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version are you using? There was a bug in v0.34 that limited the use. In v0.35 you can now have 2**31 elements in a sparse matrix.

Comment: I am using v0.34 . I will change it to 0.35 . BTW which type of bug is it . I don't find it on google.

Comment: Integer overflow. Here's what the fix looks like
```arrayLength = Math.min(Math.max(numRows*numCols,Integer.MAX_VALUE), arrayLength);```